# Is this kind of programming style too much?

Tags: java, coding-style

I know it is bad to hard code anything. Usually we do most of the environment variable by config file. For example, database property, project config, log4j, input, output.

But today I seen someone write code like this:

```
public void updateExistedRecord(SgsnMapping sgsnMapping) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            String updateSql = "";
            updateSql += "UPDATE " + schema + "." + tableSgsnMapping + " SET ";
            //other where clause

            ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(updateSql);

            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error when update an existing record on " + tableSgsnMapping + " table.\n" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            SqlHelper.close(ps);
        }
    }
```

The focus is on the table - tableSgsnMapping, it is written is other place in such way:

```
private String tableSgsnMapping = ConstantManager.TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING;
```

In turn, the TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING is define in other place:

```
public final static String TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING = "OBDUA_SGSN_MAPPING";
```

Isn't that too much? The table won't change its name and it will be always there. Why don't just hard code it in the program? Why?

Comment: tables would not change their name, but there could be multiple references for the table name in code i.e the constant could be used in more than one place. And you really do not need the private String tableSgsnMapping = ConstantManager.TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING and ConstantManager.TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING can be used straight away and further more by using static imports you could reduce it to TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING

Comment: The person best suited to answer the why question is the person who wrote that code. Why don't you ask him? The both of you know a lot more about the particular circumstances of that project than we ever will.

Answer (score 2):

There's a more serious problem with using statements created from Strings (even if they're in constants) - you might open the door to an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). From the security viewpoint, it's better to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead, setting the parameters via the `setXXX()` methods, not concatenating strings like in the question.

And it's a good idea to have the text of the prepared statement defined as a constant string in the class where it's being used, with placeholders for the parameters. For example:

```
private static final String query = 
"update dbName.tableName set field = ? where condition = ?";
```

Comment: Good Points. `PreparedStatements` are more efficiently executed by the DBMS.

Comment: PreparedStatements _are_ used in the example. And SQL-Injection is generally concerned about bad user input, not about sabotage from the development team not trusting the constants from other classes. IMO this is to paranoid for the normal use cases

Answer (score 1):

The value of `tableSgsnMapping` is always `ConstantManager.TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING`? Then I'd use this constant, maybe as a static import to save some space. Reassigning it to a local variable might be confusing to readers and introduce errors if its value is accidentally changed.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the table might not change as you say. But who knows the future?

But my main point pro `ConstantManager.TABLE_SGSN_MAPPING` is that table names and column names are usually used several times in different statements and places in the code. Using constants you can be sure, that there are no typos in *one* seldom used SQL statement regarding these things. My favourite in this corner is: Was the table name in plural form or not? ("customers" vs. "customer"). I simply don't want to think about that every time again - by using constants.